# How can I install mdk3 on linux mint?

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint, kali-linux

Every website that I look at has a different explanation and none of them seem to help me get this utility installed. Here are the best instructions I found and what went wrong. They are from the kali linux webpage on how to install on Debian.

```
git clone https://github.com/charlesxsh/mdk3-master.git

cd mdk3-master
make
sudo make install
sudo /usr/local/sbin/mdk3
```

When I type make I get: `make: *** No rule to make target 'osdep/libosdep.a', needed by 'mdk3'.  Stop.`

I have tried as root aswell as non-root using sudo. Any help would be appreciated I have spent a fair amount of time on this.

Answer (score 3):

As a general practice, it is good if you use original sources (author's repositories). The github link you provided isn't the original link. After much googling I couldn't find the original link, the author's web page seems to be down ([Here is the web-archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20140430151116/http://homepages.tu-darmstadt.de/~p_larbig/wlan)). I then looked for mdk3 in Kali Linux's repositories (Kali Linux is successor to backtrack). Since Kali Linux is a well known Linux distribution, its repositories can be trusted.

The following steps worked for me.

```
git clone git://git.kali.org/packages/mdk3.git
patch <makefile.patch #<patch the source to get rid of "undefined reference to pthread_create" while doing make
make
make install
```

Contents of the patch file, `makefile.patch` are the following.

```
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index 20182a2..e6f5739 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-CFLAGS     = -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra
+CFLAGS     = -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pthread
 LINKFLAGS  = -lpthread

 DESTDIR        =
```

I had to patch the Makefile to get rid of "`` undefined reference to `pthread_create' ``" error which I was getting while doing make. The patch simply adds `-pthread` in CLFAGS. 
 I am using `Ubuntu 15.10 (64-bit)`, but I have tested it on `Linux Mint 18 (64-bit)` as well (using live disk).

I have uploaded the patch file, and the mdk3 repository to github (So that I can use `https://` instead of `git://` for cloning, since the port for git protocol is blocked by university firewall). [Here is the link](https://github.com/lihas/mdk3). The `Makefile` in this repository is already patched.

Comment: `patch <makefile.patch < #patch the source to get rid of "undefined reference to pthread_create" while doing make` parse error near `\n'

Comment: I have updated that line slightly. The second < shouldn't be there.

Comment: Did the change work for you?